# ESP8266 + Arduino + XAMPP can't send data properly

Tags: php, arduino, xampp, esp8266, at-command

I'am working on my arduino, i wanted to connect esp with arduino and send data to my local xampp database. I have such code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial monitor(2, 3);
String GET;
String SSID = "MyNet"; //SSID
String Password = "12345678"; //Password
void setup()
{
    monitor.begin(9600);
    monitor.println("AT+CIPMUX=1");
    delay(200);
    connect_c();

}

void loop(){
  delay(15000); 

  updateDatabase(); //sending data
  delay(3600); //wait
}

void updateDatabase(){
  GET = "GET /dht.php?temperature=32&humidity=62 HTTP/1.1";//48
  String command = GET;
 command += "\n\r";
 command += "Host: 192.168.1.15";
 command += "\n\r\n\r";
  monitor.println("AT+CIPSTART=4, \"TCP\",\"192.168.1.15\",80");
  delay(5000);
  monitor.print("AT+CIPSEND=4,");
  delay(500);
  monitor.println(command.length());  

  delay(3000);
  monitor.println(command);
  delay(3000);
  monitor.println("AT+CIPCLOSE=4");/// BYLO BEZ =4
}
void connect_c(){
  monitor.println("AT+CWMODE=1");
  delay(200);
        String cmd = "AT+CWJAP=\""+SSID+"\", \""+Password+"\"";
  monitor.println(cmd);
  delay(2000);

}
```

but nothing change in my database, so i checked apache logs and i have this:

```
192.168.1.33 - - [19/Nov/2019:17:20:08 +0100] "GET /dht.php?temperature=34&humidity=64 HTTP/1.1\n" 400 980 "-" "-"
```

Do you have any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: \r\n is the right order

Comment: @Juraj i changed it, but i got the same log and nothing changed in my database

Comment: what version of AT firmware do you have?

Comment: 00200.9.5(b1)
compiled @ Dec 25 2014 21:40:28
AI-THINKER Dec 25 2014

Comment: pretty old version. you should read the responses from the AT firmware and at least print them to Serial. the delays are very long. the delay between cipsend and printing the length is for what?

Comment: I don't know, I found tutorial on the internet where somebody put that delays

Comment: @Juraj I uploaded new firmware to my ESP and now everything is working properly, Thank You very much :)

Comment: with AT 1.7.x you can use my WiFiEspAT library